# KeyError: '>R' no Python do Google Colab

Tags: html, python, data, google, ciência-de-dados

Copiei o seguinte código de um tutorial de visualização de dados em Python, mas ele não executa devidamente, avisando KeyError como visto no título. Alguém pode me ajudar? Tem algo errado aí?

```
entrada = open("/bacteria.fasta").read()
saida = open("/bacteria.html", "w")

cont = {}

for i in ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']:
    for j in ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']:
        cont[i+j] = 0

entrada = entrada.replace("\n", "")

for k in range(len(entrada)-1):
    cont[entrada[k]+entrada[k+1]] += 1

# html

i = 1
for k in cont:
    transparencia = cont[k]/max(cont.values())
    saida.write("<div style='width:100px; border:1px solid #111; height:100px; float:left; background-color:rgba(0,0,255,"+str(transparencia)+"')></div>")

saida.close()
```

O log diz o seguinte:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e27a0dec51b4> in <module>()
     13 
     14 for k in range(len(entrada)-1):
---> 15         cont[entrada[k]+entrada[k+1]] += 1
     16 
     17 # html

KeyError: '>R'
```

Comment: Pode por favor colocar na pergunta o log de erros completo?

Comment: ok, colocarei o log

Comment: Aqui em `entrada[k+1]` o índice `k+1` no último elemento `k` viola o tamanho da lista `entrada`.

Comment: Abra em bloco de texto e apaga as informações não referentes ao código genético. Para mim, funcionou certinho depois

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realizei recentemente o mesmo estudo,e consegui resolver o mesmo problema ao abrir o arquivo "bacteria.fasta" com o software Sublime Text e apagar as duas primeiras linhas que não possuem informações referentes ao código genético. 
Após salvar, o erro não apareceu novamente.

Att.